# LINQ GroupBy with multiple dynamic complex parameters

Tags: vb.net, linq, dynamic

I'm fairly new to LINQ, and for the past few days, I've been struggling to achieve the following. 
I need to group (as well, as query, and later do some aggregation stuff) a collection of rather complex objects. 
 The problem is that I need to do the query/grouping by single or multiple parameters, whose names are not known at design time. Ideally, I'd like to supply an array with strings representing the parameter names and get the the grouping done. 
 Additionally, the parameters in question are nested within a collection contained by objects-to-be-grouped. 
 Here is an example:

Objects in my collection:

```
Class qItem
    Property qName As String
    Property qStuff As String
    Property qList As List(Of qTag)
End Class
Class qTag
    Property Tag As String
    Property Value As String
End Class
```

The main collection

```
Dim qResult As New List(Of qItem)
```

The collection is populated with

```
qResult.Add(New qItem With {.qName = "N1", .qStuff = "S1", .qList = New List(Of qTag) From {
                                        New qTag With {.Tag = "T1", .Value = "VAA"},
                                        New qTag With {.Tag = "NAME", .Value = "V2"}}})
qResult.Add(New qItem With {.qName = "N1", .qStuff = "S3", .qList = New List(Of qTag) From {
                                        New qTag With {.Tag = "T1", .Value = "V1"},
                                        New qTag With {.Tag = "NAME", .Value = "V2"}}})
qResult.Add(New qItem With {.qName = "N2", .qStuff = "S1", .qList = New List(Of qTag) From {
                                        New qTag With {.Tag = "T1", .Value = "V1"},
                                        New qTag With {.Tag = "NAME", .Value = "VZZ"}}})
qResult.Add(New qItem With {.qName = "N2", .qStuff = "S3", .qList = New List(Of qTag) From {
                                        New qTag With {.Tag = "T1", .Value = "V1"},
                                        New qTag With {.Tag = "NAME", .Value = "VZZ"}}})
qResult.Add(New qItem With {.qName = "N2", .qStuff = "S1", .qList = New List(Of qTag) From {
                                        New qTag With {.Tag = "T1", .Value = "VAA"},
                                        New qTag With {.Tag = "NAME", .Value = "VZZ"}}})
```

Now. I'd like to group objects in `qResult` by the `Value` property from `qTag` object in the collection contained by the `qItem`. The grouping should be done by `Tag` properties of the `qTag` object.

 
If I need to group by only one parameter, I can do this:

```
Dim R = From q In qResult
            Group By q.qList.FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.Tag = "NAME")?.Value
                Into Group
```

Where `"NAME"` is the value I can pass to do the grouping. 
If I need to group by multiple parameters (for example `"NAME"` and `"T1"`), I learned, that I can do this:

```
    Dim Rt = From q In qResult
         Group By MyGrouping = New With {
                 Key .g1 = q.qList.FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.Tag = "NAME")?.Value,
                 Key .g2 = q.qList.FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.Tag = "T1")?.Value
                 }
                Into Group
```

But now, I can no longer supply the grouping information dynamically. For that, I would somehow need to generate the anonymous type with dynamic properties.

After that I've looked into **Dynamic LINQ** as described [here](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library).

With that, I learned that I can do the grouping like this. For example, if I needed to group by simple properties of the `qitem`

```
Dim Rt1 = qResult.GroupBy("new (qName, qStuff)", "it")
```

This works and I can pass the information as array as well

```
Dim GroupingParams As String() = {"qName", "qStuff"}
Dim Rt2 = qResult.GroupBy("new (" & String.Join(",", GroupingParams) & ")", "it")
```

But this only works for properties of the `qitem`. My initial goal was to group items by the `Value` property in `qTag` in a collection contained in `qItem`. 
It seems, that Dynamic LINQ does some sort of evaluating here `"new (qName, qStuff)"`. Though, I could not find a comprehensive description of what can or cannot be evaluated. So this doesn't work

```
Dim Rt3 = qResult.GroupBy("qList.FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.Tag = ""NAME"")?.Value,", "it")
```

Is it possible to pass this to Dynamic Linq?  
 Or should start looking into reflection or dynamic anonymous types? (though, I'm not sure whether the regular LINQ `Group By` will accept such a anonymous type)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you don't use the lambda `Function(x)` construct, it is implicit:

```
Dim Rt3 = qResult.AsQueryable.GroupBy("iif(qList.FirstOrDefault(Tag = ""NAME"") == null, null, qList.FirstOrDefault(Tag = ""NAME"").Value)", "it")
```

Note: You can't use a null-propagating operator in an `Expression` tree (because C# has woefully neglected updating `Expression`) and `np()` isn't flexible enough to handle this, so you must manually expand out the test, and run `FirstOrDefault` twice :( If you could get away with using `First` instead, it is simply:

```
Dim Rt3 = qResult.AsQueryable.GroupBy("qList.First(Tag = ""NAME"").Value", "it")
```

For grouping by an anonymous object, you must make sure you don't have duplicate field names so use `as` to name each field:

```
Dim Rt3 = qResult.AsQueryable.GroupBy("new (qList.FirstOrDefault(Tag = ""T1"").Value as T1,qList.FirstOrDefault(Tag = ""NAME"").Value as Name)", "it")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Maybe, I'm using some different version of Dynamic Linq, not sure. Just to be clear, I'm using the NugGet package "System.Linq.Dynamic" by Microsoft. Anyway, it doesn't seem to like `First` of `FirstOrDefault` and I get an error `System.Linq.Dynamic.ParseException: 'No applicable aggregate method 'First' exists'`

Comment: @EdgarsMiškins Yes, I tested with `System.Linq.Dynamic.Core`. I can try with the original MS version instead if you can't switch.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I can switch. I just started looking into Dynamic Linq, so it's not a problem. And yes, it works when I switched to `System.Linq.Dynamic.Core`. Quick queston. How would it work with multiple parameters? I tried `qResult.AsQueryable.GroupBy("new (qList.First(Tag = ""T1"").Value, qList.First(Tag = ""NAME"").Value)", "it")` but I get an error `System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException: 'Ambiguous match found.'`

Comment: @EdgarsMiškins Just like a C# anonymous type, you can't have two fields with the same name, so you need to put `as T1` and `as Name` after the two field expressions to name the fields.